# How to handle Wicket session per client using aop

Tags: java, aop, wicket, spring-aop

I am using Wicket 1.4.9 + Spring 3 + iBatis. I want to get session data before used transactional but I have a big problem because this data put on Wicket web session(this data choose on login page).

I am using spring aop for point cut but I cannot point cut session per client. How to solve this problem.

User Class Entity

```
package com.app.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class User implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String crtUser;
    private Date crtDate;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCrtUser() {
        return crtUser;
    }

    public void setCrtUser(String crtUser) {
        this.crtUser = crtUser;
    }

    public Date getCrtDate() {
        return crtDate;
    }

    public void setCrtDate(Date crtDate) {
        this.crtDate = crtDate;
    }

}
```

Web App Class

```
package com.app.conf;

import org.apache.wicket.Page;
import org.apache.wicket.Request;
import org.apache.wicket.Response;
import org.apache.wicket.Session;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector;

import com.app.page.UserLoginPage;

public class WebApp extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        addComponentInstantiationListener(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return UserLoginPage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
        return new CustomSession(request);
    }

}
```

Custom session class

```
package com.app.conf;

import org.apache.wicket.Request;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession;

import com.app.entity.User;

public class CustomSession extends WebSession {

    private User user;

    public CustomSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

User Login Page : Keep Session when Login

```
package com.app.page;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.PasswordTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

import com.app.conf.CustomSession;
import com.app.entity.User;

public class UserLoginPage extends WebPage {

    private LoginForm form;

    public UserLoginPage() {
        form = new LoginForm("form");
        add(form);
    }

    private class LoginForm extends Form{

        private User user;

        private TextField<String> username;
        private PasswordTextField password;
        private AjaxButton submitButton;

        public LoginForm(String id) {
            super(id);

            user = new User();

            username = new TextField<String>("username",
                    new PropertyModel<String>(this, "user.username"));
            add(username);

            password = new PasswordTextField("password" , 
                    new PropertyModel<String>(this, "user.password"));
            add(password);

            submitButton = new AjaxButton("submitButton", this) {

                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget arg0, Form<?> arg1) {
                    getCustomSession().setUser(user);
                    setResponsePage(new UserAddPage());
                }
            };
            add(submitButton);
        }
    }

    public CustomSession getCustomSession(){
        return (CustomSession)getSession();
    }

}
```

User add page : i want point cut insert on Service Class method and get session for add Create user and Create date on User Entity Class

```
package com.app.page;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.PasswordTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;

import com.app.entity.User;
import com.app.service.IUserService;

public class UserAddPage extends WebPage {

    @SpringBean private IUserService userService;

    private UserAddForm form;

    public UserAddPage() {
        form = new UserAddForm("form");
        add(form);
    }

    private class UserAddForm extends Form {

        private User user;

        private TextField<String> name;
        private TextField<String> lastname;
        private TextField<String> username;
        private PasswordTextField password;
        private AjaxButton submitButton;

        public UserAddForm(String id) {
            super(id);
            user = new User();

            name = new TextField<String>("name",
                    new PropertyModel<String>(this, "user.name"));
            add(name);

            lastname = new TextField<String>("lastname" , 
                    new PropertyModel<String>(this, "user.lastname"));
            add(lastname);

            username = new TextField<String>("username",
                    new PropertyModel<String>(this, "user.username"));
            add(username);

            password = new PasswordTextField("password" , 
                    new PropertyModel<String>(this, "user.password"));
            add(password);

            submitButton = new AjaxButton("submitButton", this) {

                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget arg0, Form<?> arg1) {
                    /*
                     * HOW TO POINT CUT THIS METHOD AND GET SESSION BEFORE INSERT
                     */
                    userService.insert(user);
                }
            };
            add(submitButton);
        }

    }

}
```

User Aspect

```
package com.app.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import com.app.entity.User;

@Aspect
public class UserAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.app.service..*.insert*(..))&&" + "args(user)")
    public void userPointcut(User user){}

    @Around("userPointcut(user)")
    public Object aroundUser(ProceedingJoinPoint pj, User user) throws Throwable{
        /*
         * How to get Create User from Session
         */
        return pj.proceed();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is interesting and I'll be glad to give it a shot if you supply some more info. What's the data, when is it created, when is the session created, what do you need it for. Why don't you show some sample code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Help me ! for solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

WebApp.getSession().getUser()  ?

I'd imagine that you want to register a bean in the spring context that can supply an authorised user. This can retrieve the user from your WebApp session (the WebApp instance would also be a registered bean, but I assume it is already). There should be plenty of information on this use-case in the spring docs/community.

For better answers, you should clean up your question (use of code blocks) and state the use case.